# AWS lambda function with python "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index'"

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i am trying to make a post call from lambda function but not able to run the code on aws console but it it working properly on my system.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the dependencies in the folder where you have `index.py` then you need to zip the contents of the folder and upload the zip file to AWS Lambda.

Please note that you need to zip the contents of the folder, do not zip the folder itself.

On windows, you can install the packages in the folder using below command:

```
pip install package-name -t "/path/to/project-dir"
```

Comment: then why cant we see the packages in the file listing in your screenshot? there should have been a folder named `requests` among other things

Comment: maybe that's the problem. in windows it does not work like that, no idea about MAC.

Comment: Your dependancies should be in the same directory as index.py (in the root of the zip). In this case, `requests`.

Comment: @sid8491its working great. i am getting my data i just have one more question how can i put this data to my lex bot.

Comment: you need to return with dialogAction with type Close. read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#lambda-response-dialogAction

Comment: @sid8491i am having issue while doing this i am uploading my code can u please correct it? bcz i am getting null response

Comment: @Pulkit i would suggest you to rollback your changes and post a new question with correct heading, tags and details, so that people can help you and people having similar problem can take some advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error today, and this is the first result on Google, so I'll add my answer. In short, I had specified the handler incorrectly on the command line when I uploaded the function.

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name python-test-lambda --runtime python3.7 --role arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/service-role/rolearn --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler --zip-file fileb://lambda_function.zip
```

ie this part was incorrect

> --handler